# How to configure custom AccessDecisionManager and custom AuthenticationProvider in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

Below is my security configuration file, which I want to change into java config

```
<beans:bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <beans:property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="securityMetadataSource" ref="securityMetadataSource" />
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthentication"></authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean name="accessDecisionManager" class="com.xy.security.CustomAccessDecisionManager" ></beans:bean>

<beans:bean name="securityMetadataSource" class="com..xy.security.InvocationSecurityMetadataSourceService">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="customAuthentication" class="com.xy.security.CustomAuthentication" />

<beans:bean id="securityExceptionTranslationHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <beans:property name="exceptionMappings">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException">/changepassword.xhtml</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.jsp" />
</beans:bean>    ====================================================
```

I want to change this to java config below is my code but it's failing

```
@Configuration

@EnableWebSecurity

public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthentication customAuthentication;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAccessDecisionManager customAccessDecisionManager;

    @Autowired
    private InvocationSecurityMetadataSourceService invocationSecurityMetadataSourceService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthentication);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login*","/favicon.ico","/","/**/*.css" ,"/images/*.*","/js/*.js","/bt-fonts/*.*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin*")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login").invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("true")
            .and()
            .authenticationProvider(customAuthentication)
            //.accessDecisionManager(customAccessDecisionManager)
            //.authorizeRequests().accessDecisionManager(customAccessDecisionManager)
            //.csrf().disable()
            ;

    }
```

I have a class where I have custom Authentication logic

```
public class CustomAccessDecisionManager implements AccessDecisionManager{

  -@Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication){
```

// some code here
}

```
}
```

and another class like below where I have custom Authorization logic

```
public class CustomAuthentication implements AuthenticationProvider{

  @Override
    public void decide(Authentication arg0, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> arg2)
```

// some code here

```
}
```

Comment: Do you receive an exception? If so post the stacktrace.

Comment: Is there anything wrong in my configuration of my customAutentication and customAccessMgr in the SecurityConfig class ?

Comment: If i'm configuring csrf().disable() then control is not going anywhere it is again coming back to my login page. And after removing csrf() and after entering userid and pwd the control isgoing to appropriate jsp page but control is not coming to my customAutentication and customAccessMgr class. In the browser it is giving error----- This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403). Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

Answer (score -1):

The first (I would recommend) is to update your configuration to include a WebExpressionVoter. For example:

```
     @Bean
public AccessDecissionManager defaultAccessDecisionManager() {
    List<AccessDecisionVoter<FilterInvocation>> voters = new ArrayList<AccessDecisionVoter<FilterInvocation>>();
    voters.add(new WebExpressionVoter());
    voters.add(new CustomVoter());
    AccessDecissionManager result = new UnanimousBased();
    result.setDecisionVoters(voters);
    return result;
}
```

The second option is to change to not use expressions within Spring Security's url mappings. For example

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 http
    .apply(new UrlAuthorizationConfigurer())
        .accessDecisionManager(defaultAccessDecisionManager())
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMINGROUP")
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
    ....
```

}

[view the below link](https://gist.github.com/yashpatil/3f86f8bde7f765e8fb389c64e7a9c5a7)

Answer (score -1):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        /**
         * Do your stuff here
         */
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```